# How to change the major and minor number of a device file?

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, serial-port

I am currently working with an Embedded Linux Board and need to use the serial port, which is represented by the device file /dev/ttyS0. Upon running the command `ls -l`, I observed that the major and minor numbers for this device are 247 and 0, respectively. However, according to the [Linux Allocated Devices Guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html), these numbers should be 4 and 64. How can I change them to the correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have a different module that creates the device and the module determines the major & minor numbers. Use the commands

```
readlink /sys/dev/char/247\:0/device/driver
udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyS0
```

to find out what module is controlling the device. It may not be the usual PNP subsystem and serial driver. If the device is working then you should be ok. If it isn't you will need some more information, perhaps from `dmesg` and digging into the module. You cannot change the device number without changing the kernel module.

Comment: You are right. I find out that I have a different custom module handling the device. The serial driver is working.

Comment: is there a way to spoof the major number, perhaps with `mknod` and `ln`?

Comment: @moFEAR No. The kernel device drivers have the major number hard-coded in them. As an example, try `mknod -m 0666  /tmp/foo c 1 3 && ps -fe>/tmp/foo`. All output will go to the bit bucket as if you had used `/dev/null`.